# Disabling command+scrolling in TeXstudio (OS X)

Tags: mac, texstudio, keyboard

Is there any way to disable cmd+scroll zooming in TeXStudio for OS X?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know if it is the same in OSX but on Linux you can do this via `Options>Configure TeXstudio` and then choose the tab `Adv. Editor`, as you can see on the image below. After, note that there is an option *Mouse Wheel Zoom* on the *Special Options* section.

[image]

ps: note that *Show Advanced Options* is turned on, on the left bottom corner.

Comment: I can confirm it works also on Mac OS X; one has to relaunch TeXStudio for the setting to have effect. TeXstudio 2.5.2 (SVN 3651M)

Comment: To be true, I discovered this feature just now and also discovered how to disable it. lol